# Why do Java collections not provide a convenient map method?

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I'm wondering why the Java Collections API doesn't contain handy `map` methods on the different collection types. I would like to write something like:

```
List<Foo> list = ...;    
List<String> result = list.map(Foo::toString);
```

Instead I have to create a stream, map and collect, like this:

```
List<Foo> list = ...; 
List<String> result = list.stream().map(Foo::toString).collect(toList());
```

Wouldn't it be as easy as implementing this default method in the java.util.List interface? E.g.

```
default <R> List<R> map(Function<E, R> mapper){
    return stream().map(mapper).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

On first sight, it seems like other convenients methods are in place. For example:

```
list.stream().forEach(x -> {});
```

can be written as

```
list.forEach(x -> {});
```

However, the comparision is not that good. Iteratable.forEach is a default method on the top level interface and doesn't need to specify a return type. It's not creating a stream under the hood, but rather using Iteratables properties to... well... iterate all elements.

So the question remains: 
Why not have a map method on each and every Collections API interface? Maybe because it's not flexible enough because you would need to decide on a return type?

I'm sure the implementors thought about it and had their reasons to not put it in. And I would like to understand why.

Comment: Just four days earlier: [“Why does `List` not have a `map` default method when it has `forEach`?”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42364761/2711488)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this is deliberate.  Some reasons I've heard discussed:

- many times, these methods are chained together, in which case it's more efficient to only collect into an explicit data structure at the end of the computation
- control the absolute size of the interface; manage the number of options appearing in autocomplete
- avoid conflicts with outside implementations of `Collection` that already provided methods named `map`, etc.
- build all the fluent features into one coherent API with specialized configuration methods like `parallel()`; and that API can now be evolved separately from the collections it's built on
- as you mentioned, let the user explicitly decide on an implementation of the return type -- if you had an arbitrary `Collection` and called `map` on it, it could either be a `List`, or a `Set` that silently deduplicates its output?! that'd be super confusing

Comment: In addition to this answer I would add that Java collections typically have mutation operations, but `map` is expected to leave the original list untouched. Instead there is `List.replaceAll(UnaryOperator)` which applies an operator to all list elements in place.